# Is there a way to check if memcached has been restarted?

Tags: c#, c++, memcached

I tagged this question additionally with C++ and C# because both languages in the project are affected.

**The situation:**

1. Modules in the mentioned languages are communicating via `memcached`. They are running - together with `memcached` - for months without any problem.
2. `memcached` is running on another server.
3. For performance reasons the connections to `memcached` remain all the time *open*, this means once, when each module started it connects to `memcached` and reuses this connection until the modules stops.

Now, there is a very rare situation that the VM on which `memcached` is running restarts - I cannot control it.
In such case I see that the modules have undefined behavior.

**My question:**
Is there a way how I can detect that the instance of `memcached` became invalid due to a restart?
In this case I would reconnect again.

*The other point is:* Should this *check* take more or less the same time as a reconnect if it is not a good idea I reconnect each time it is needed and then I avoid any problem when the `memcached` server restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution - it seems it is easier than I thought:

A *reference* memcached key - for example `HasMemcachedBeenRestarted` - will be created when a module starts. The value will be set to `NO`.

The modules are running as threads and they wake up by an external trigger. In such a case they read this memcached key and when it doesn't have the value `NO` then it is clear that `memcached` has been restarted and they then reconnect.

Due to the fact I have to do it once for each *thread-wake-up* it does not have any performance impact.

---

PS: In my case it is not that trivial because there are several hundred of threads so I have to add to each *reference* memcached key a hash in order each thread can check the situation.

Otherwise the 1st thread would realize that `memcached` has been restarted and would set the *reference* key again to `NO` which would lead to the situation that other threads would *think* all is OK even the internal connection became invalid.

Comment: Indeed very simple method and in the end so obvious!